# Part Size seems to be ignored

Tags: roblox

I have a part, created with

```lua
local p = Instance.new("Part")  
p.Size = Vector3.new(2, 2, 2)
```

That part uses a mesh like

```lua
local m = Instance.new("SpecialMesh", p)
m.MeshType = Enum.MeshType.FileMesh
m.MeshId = "rbxassetid://7974596857"
```

which is a cube with rounded corners that I created in blender

[image]

When I put those beside each other, it seems like the Size property actually is ignored.

Why?

## size 2

```lua
p1.Position = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0)
p1.Size = Vector3.new(2, 2, 2)

p2.Position = Vector3.new(5, 5, 0)
p2.Size = Vector3.new(2, 2, 2)
```

[image]

## size 5

```lua
p1.Position = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0)
p1.Size = Vector3.new(5, 5, 5)

p2.Position = Vector3.new(5, 5, 0)
p2.Size = Vector3.new(5, 5, 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because special meshes have [their own scaling property](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/DataModelMesh/Scale). If possible, [use a MeshPart](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/MeshPart) instead.